# Using dvb-t device as rtl-sdr

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr

I am wondering if I can use [that](https://www.hepsiburada.com/gob2c-usb-2-0-mini-dijital-dvb-t-hdtv-uzaktan-kumanda-p-HBV00000LDJXT?magaza=GOB2C%20Global) dvb-t device to listen 48-836 mhz?

[image: product]

[image: frequence]

if it's no, why?
thanks..

Answer (score 4):

*If* the specific device is built around the Realtek RTL2832U chip, then the `rtl-sdr` driver software will be able to use it as an SDR.

If it uses a different chip, then that driver will not work. It *might* still be possible to use that hardware, but would require writing new driver software and possibly reverse-engineering (the same as the original RTL-SDR development project).

It is also worth noticing that `rtl-sdr` actually does not use the DVB-T capabilities of the devices it works with at all — the raw-samples mode of the chip is narrow-band compared to what is required to receive DVB-T and was used by the original software to receive FM radio, not video. Hardware that *only* has a DVB-T mode *cannot* be used as a SDR.